# How to pass all state values to number of child components and update the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and I have some challenge in my first app. In my app I have parent component and more then one child component, in parent component I have state with values that I need to pass to all of my child components, in every child component if the state was update I need the parent gets update too, but I struggle how to pass all state values to child components.

In my parent component (NavigatorRiddles) I am using navigator, my child components are HomeScreen and Riddles:

```
export default class NavigatorRiddles extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userAnswer: '', count: 0, diamonds: 0, urldatabase: {}, wordsnumber: 0, riddleletter: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <HomeScreen getState={...this.state}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class RiddlesScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Riddles navigation={this.props.navigation} getState={...this.state}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const Navigate = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Riddles: { screen: RiddlesScreen },
  },

)
```

In the child components I don't new how to make the component actually to get that state

every help really appreciated!
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you could pass down your state like so:

```
<HomeScreen navigatorState={this.state} />
```

and then access this prop in the child:

```
class RiddlesScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.navigatorState) // { userAnswer: '', count: 0, diamonds: 0, urldatabase: {}, wordsnumber: 0, riddleletter: '' }
    return (
      <View>
        <Riddles navigation={this.props.navigation} getState={...this.state}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I get null... what I need to do new?

Comment: The log is `null`?